# converting a project from .net 4.5.2 to .net standard 1.4

Tags: .net

I'm working on upgrading my companies enterprise logging library from .net 4.5.2 to .net standard 1.4. As expected a lot of the dependencies aren't compatible. My googlefu is failing me and I was wondering if anyone knows of a resource where I can find out where some of my dependencies have been moved in .net standard.

Answer (score 2):

When using Visual Studio 2015 or 2017 it helps installing the [.NET Portability Analyzer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ConnieYau.NETPortabilityAnalyzer) to see which parts of code are compatible with a specific version of the framework.

When using NuGet packages in one or more projects of your solution it helps running your `packages.config` files through the https://icanhasdot.net/ site to see which dependencies are already ported to .NET Core.